# Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.FDBDIF32' or one of its dependencies in WCF Service reference when run the Project

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Getting Error in WCF Service. i converted project vs2010 to vs2013 and in WCF service reference showing below Error when run the project:

**Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.**

**Parser Error Message: Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.FDBDIF32, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.**

[image]

Comment: The error message is quite clear - it can't find the referenced assembly.  Did you by chance load the project onto a different machine that doesn't have the needed assembly(ies)?

Comment: Thanks for reply but i solved it. yes it was assembly problem.